# How do I make a HashSet from an iterator of chars?

Tags: rust, iterator, hashset

I'm just starting to learn Rust and I'm still working on understanding its approach. The particular thing I'm working on is trying to find out if two strings have any characters in common. In another language I might do this by creating two sets of the characters in the strings and performing an intersection on the sets. So far I'm having no luck in creating a `HashSet` from the characters in a string in Rust. I'm trying variations on this:

```rust
let lines: Vec<&str> = text_from_file.lines().collect();
let set1 = HashSet::from(lines[0].chars());
```

With this variation I get the error "the trait bound `std::collections::HashSet<_, _>: std::convert::From<&[u8]>` is not satisfied". I don't understand Rust enough yet to know how to interpret this. How can I create a `HashSet` from the characters in a string?

Comment: Note that I'm geting a different error when I [try it in Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1db5c1f9c0960181210bf7337c02fced): "the trait bound `HashSet<_, _>: From<Chars<'_>>` is not satisfied".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `HashSet::from_iter()`

```
let lines: Vec<&str> = text_from_file.lines().collect();
let set1: HashSet<char> = HashSet::from_iter(lines[0].chars());
```

Comment: Is there an advantage to `HashSet::from_iter(lines[0].chars())` over `lines[0].chars().collect()` or are they basically equivalent?

Comment: @SSteve They're equivalent. `collect()` basically calls `from_iter()`. `collect()` is nicer at the end (or middle) of method chains.

Answer (score 3):

`HashSet::from()` requires a slice as parameter, but `lines[0].chars()` is a `Chars` object, which is an iterator.

To create a `HashSet` from an iterator, you have two possibilities:

```rust
let set1: HashSet<char> = lines[0].chars().collect();
```

```rust
let set1: HashSet<char> = HashSet::from_iter(lines[0].chars());
```

I prefer the first one, as it's much easier to read for me.